# Writing permission to symlink

Tags: permissions, docker, symlink, remote

I have a directory (linux container) on a remote server to which I don't have writing access. I created a symlink to use this container locally. When I run the symlink of the container with docker locally, it tries to create some temporary file on that container (and fails, as the source directory has no write access). I want a symlink to this container, but the symlink should have access to write inside it locally.

P.S - I don't want to copy this container locally since it is too big.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a symlink to this container, but the symlink should have access to write inside it locally.

That's impossible, and not at all what a symblink is. You need a different method.

Docker has this whole idea of layers. Look at a Dockerfile of your choice: the first lines specify which existing container image the to-be-built image is based upon.

Use that here – as long as you use the same base image for two different containers, only the files in which these two containers differ from the base image will take up space.

Unter the hood, that's mostly overlayfs. That's the more general approach to "I have a local directory, to which I want to do changes, without modifying the original". But, again, Docker has the layer system *exactly* for this purpose.